# execute a command from a batch file from a different folder

Tags: angularjs, node.js, batch-file

I have 3 folders on same level (Folder 1,Folder 2 & Folder 3) inside a parent Folder named "MyApp" and my .bat file is in Folder 1. In Folder 2 I have my Angular app files and node server. Is there a way where I can write in my batch file to execute some commands ("npm start") the npm modules are in Folder 2. 
Something like this

```
echo "Starting App Module"
cd "\Folder 2"
start "" npm start
```

I don't want to give the absolute path like this(below) which works fine.

```
echo "Starting App Module"
CD D:\MyApp\Folder 2 
start ""npm start
```

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: You could try the relative path, `"cd ..\Folder 2"`

Comment: Thanks it works!!, why didn't I think of this before :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of possible solutions. I think, the best one for your task is:

```
echo "Starting App Module"
start "" "%~dp0..\Folder 2\npm.exe" start
```

`%~dp0` ... references drive and path of batch file ending with a backslash. Run in a command prompt window `call /?` and read all help pages output for details.

Now it does not matter which directory is the current directory on start of the batch file. `npm.exe` is started with a path relative to path of the batch file independent on current working directory set for the batch file.